# A FOR LOOP inside a WHILE LOOP in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an input file of names and need to search for all matches in a database. I am using the while loop to step through the input file and the for loop to step through the cursor. I am getting the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 289, column 3:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null raise
> return select update while with 
>   <<
> continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
> savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
> json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array

---

code:

```
--
-- ************************************************************
--
-- Program Name:         DataGathering_Step1.sql
-- Date Written:         Dec 9, 2020
-- Author:               St. Norbert College - Computer Services
-- Supporting Members:
-- Requesting Dept       ITS
-- Dept Contact
-- Operation Date        xx/xx/xxxx
--
-- Program Notes,Purpose and Comments
--
-- Special Rules or Notes
--
-- Changes - Date, who and comments on change.
--
--
--

CLEAR screen

/* SET echo OFF;
SET SHOW OFF;
SET ver OFF;
SET feed OFF;
*/

--
-- Get external parameters and general setup
--

define DataInFile = &1
define DataOutFile = &2
define EmailTo1 = &3

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON size 50000;

DECLARE

/* define the cursor for selecting a person based on first and last name. */
CURSOR c_person (v_fname   varchar2, vlname   varchar2) IS
select distinct i.spriden_id c_id,
       i.spriden_first_name c_fname,  
       i.spriden_mi c_mi,
       i.spriden_last_name c_lname,  
       p.spbpers_name_suffix c_suffix,
       a.spraddr_street_line1 c_street1, 
       a.spraddr_street_line2 c_street2,
       a.spraddr_street_line3 c_street3, 
       a.spraddr_city c_city, 
       a.spraddr_stat_code c_state,
       a.spraddr_zip c_zip, 
       p.spbpers_birth_date c_bdate,
       p.spbpers_ssn c_ssn
from spriden i, spbpers p, spraddr a
where i.spriden_pidm = p.spbpers_pidm
and i.spriden_pidm = a.spraddr_pidm
and a.spraddr_atyp_code = 'P'
and a.spraddr_to_date is null
and upper(i.spriden_first_name) like upper('v_fname%')
and upper(i.spriden_last_name) like upper('v_lname');



  v_FileLocation               VARCHAR2(290)                                      := 'L';

-- variables for input data file

  v_workfield                  VARCHAR2(255)                                      := NULL;
  v_crn_count                  NUMBER(4)                                          := 0;

-- END variables for input data file

-- variables needed to verify input information and build output data file

  v_id                         SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID%TYPE                            := NULL;
  v_pidm                       SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM%TYPE                          := NULL;
  v_last_name                  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME%TYPE                     := NULL;
  v_first_name                 SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME%TYPE                    := NULL;
  v_middle                     SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_MI%TYPE                            := NULL;
  v_suffix                     SPBPERS.SPBPERS_NAME_SUFFIX%TYPE                   := NULL;
  v_birthdate_in               SPBPERS.SPBPERS_BIRTH_DATE%TYPE                    := NULL;
  v_birthdate                  SPBPERS.SPBPERS_BIRTH_DATE%TYPE                    := NULL;
  v_ssn_in                     SPBPERS.SPBPERS_SSN%TYPE                           := NULL;
  v_ssn                        SPBPERS.SPBPERS_SSN%TYPE                           := NULL;
  v_street1                    SPRADDR.SPRADDR_STREET_LINE1%TYPE                  := NULL;
  v_street2                    SPRADDR.SPRADDR_STREET_LINE2%TYPE                  := NULL;
  v_street3                    SPRADDR.SPRADDR_STREET_LINE3%TYPE                  := NULL;
  v_city                       SPRADDR.SPRADDR_CITY%TYPE                          := NULL;
  v_state                      SPRADDR.SPRADDR_STAT_CODE%TYPE                     := NULL;
  v_zip                        SPRADDR.SPRADDR_ZIP%TYPE                           := NULL;
  v_notes                      VARCHAR2(300)                                      := ' ';
  v_lookup_ind                 VARCHAR2(1)                                        := NULL;
  v_process_ind                VARCHAR2(13)                                       := NULL;
  

-- END variables needed to verify input information and build output data file

  v_master_error               VARCHAR2(1)                                        := 'N';
  v_process_flag               VARCHAR2(3)                                        := 'Y';
  v_process_ctr                NUMBER                                             := '0';
  v_insert_ctr                 NUMBER                                             := '0';
  v_found_ctr                  NUMBER                                             := '0';
  v_master_error_ctr           NUMBER                                             := '0';
  v_fatal_comment                VARCHAR2(13)                                     := NULL;
  v_error_code                VARCHAR2(13)                                        := NULL;
  v_error_messages                VARCHAR2(13)                                        := NULL;
  v_row_error                VARCHAR2(13)                                        := NULL;

-- variables for output and input data files

  v_field_sep                  VARCHAR2(4)                                        := CHR(009);

  v_InPathname                 varchar2(55)                                       := 'SNC_READ_AREA';
  v_InFilename                 varchar2(355)                                      := '&DataInFile';
  v_LinebuffIn                 varchar2(300)                                      := NULL;
  v_FileHandleIn               UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

  v_crrt                       VARCHAR2(4)                                        := CHR(013);

  v_OutPathname                VARCHAR2(55)                                       := 'SNC_WRITE_AREA';
  v_OutFilename                VARCHAR2(355)                                      := '&DataOutFile';
  v_LinebuffOut                VARCHAR2(6000);
  v_FileHandleOut              UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

-- END variables for output and input data files

-- variables for Emailing

  message                      VARCHAR2(31000)                                    := NULL;
  v_tab                        VARCHAR2(6)                                        := CHR(009);
  crlf                         VARCHAR2(2)                                        := CHR(13) || CHR(10);
  mailhost                     VARCHAR2(30)                                       := 'cwisrelay.snc.edu';
  mail_conn                    utl_smtp.connection;
  sender                       VARCHAR2(90)                                       := 'darlene.blaney@snc.edu';
  v_recipient                  VARCHAR2(90)                                       := '&EmailTo1';
  v_email_subject              VARCHAR2(160)                                      := 'CS - Data Processing for ' || v_InFilename;
  v_email_date                 VARCHAR2(250)                                      := NULL;

-- END variables for Emailing


-- Core program

BEGIN

  v_FileHandleOut := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(v_OutPathname,v_OutFilename,'W');

  v_LinebuffOut := ('"SequenceNo"'
                || v_field_sep || '"Banner ID"'
                || v_field_sep || '"First Name"'
                || v_field_sep || '"Middle"'
                || v_field_sep || '"Last Name"'
                || v_field_sep || '"Suffix"'
                || v_field_sep || '"Street1"'
                || v_field_sep || '"Street2"'
                || v_field_sep || '"Street3"'
                || v_field_sep || '"City"'
                || v_field_sep || '"State"'
                || v_field_sep || '"Zip"'
                || v_field_sep || '"BirthDate"'
                || v_field_sep || '"SSN"'
                || v_field_sep || '"Notes"'
                || v_crrt);
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_FileHandleOut,v_LinebuffOut);

  v_FileHandleIn := utl_file.fopen (v_InPathname,v_InFilename, 'R');

<<curs_loop>>
  WHILE v_process_flag = 'Y' loop

--    v_fatal_comment := NULL;
--    v_master_error := 'N';
    v_process_flag := 'Y';

-- Get the next row and get the necessary values

    BEGIN
      utl_file.get_line (v_FileHandleIn, v_LinebuffIn);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INVALID_PATH');
        utl_file.fclose_all;
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        v_process_flag := 'N';
        GOTO NextRow;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        v_error_code := SQLCODE;
        v_error_messages := v_error_messages || SQLERRM || crlf;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error: ' || v_error_code || ' ' || SQLERRM || '  ' || v_process_ctr);
        v_process_flag := 'N';
        GOTO NextRow;
    END;

-- Input File - Position 1 - First Name

    v_workfield := SUBSTR(v_LinebuffIn, 1, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 1)-1);
    v_workfield := UPPER(v_workfield);
    v_workfield := TRIM(v_workfield);
    v_workfield := NVL(v_workfield,'END');
    v_first_name := v_workfield;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 1: ' || v_workfield);
    IF v_workfield = 'END' THEN
      v_process_flag := 'N';
      v_row_error := 'N';
      GOTO NextRow;
    ELSIF v_workfield = 'FIRST' THEN
      GOTO NextRow;
    END IF;
      

-- Input File - Position 2 - Middle Name

      v_workfield := SUBSTR(v_LinebuffIn, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 1)+1, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 2)-INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 1)-1);
      v_workfield := UPPER(v_workfield);
      v_workfield := TRIM(v_workfield);
      v_middle := NVL(v_workfield,'');
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 2: ' || v_middle);

-- Input File = Position 3 - Last Name

      v_workfield := SUBSTR(v_LinebuffIn, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 2)+1, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 3)-INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 2)-1);
      v_workfield := TRIM(v_workfield);
      v_workfield := NVL(v_workfield,'');
      v_last_name := v_workfield;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 3: ' || v_last_name);

-- Input File - Position 4 - Suffix

      v_workfield := SUBSTR(v_LinebuffIn, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 3)+1, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 4)-INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 3)-1);
      v_workfield := TRIM(v_workfield);
      v_workfield := UPPER(v_workfield);
      v_suffix := NVL(v_suffix,'');
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 4: ' || v_suffix);

-- Input File - Position 5 - Date of Birth

      v_workfield := SUBSTR(v_LinebuffIn, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 4)+1, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 5)-INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 4)-1);
      v_workfield := TRIM(v_workfield);
      v_workfield := UPPER(v_workfield);
      v_workfield := REPLACE(v_workfield,' ','');
      v_workfield := REPLACE(v_workfield,',','');
      v_workfield := NVL(v_workfield,'NODATE');
      IF (SUBSTR(v_workfield,2,1) <> '/' AND SUBSTR(v_workfield,3,1) <> '/') THEN
         v_workfield := 'NODATE';
      END IF;
      IF v_workfield = 'NODATE' THEN
         v_birthdate_in := NULL;
      ELSE
         BEGIN
           v_birthdate_in := TO_DATE(v_workfield,'mm/dd/YYYY');
         EXCEPTION
           WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
             v_birthdate_in := NULL;
             v_row_error := 'Y';
             v_error_messages := v_error_messages || '  Fatal: R' || v_process_ctr || ' Invalid Date (birthdate).' || v_crlf;
         END;
      END IF; 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 5: ' || v_birthdate);

-- Input File - Position 6 - SSN 

      v_workfield := SUBSTR(v_LinebuffIn, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 5)+1, INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 6)-INSTR(v_LinebuffIn, v_field_sep, 1, 5)-1);
      v_workfield := TRIM(v_workfield);
      v_workfield := UPPER(v_workfield);
      v_workfield := NVL(v_workfield,'00');
      v_ssn := LPAD(v_ssn,9,'0');
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 6: ' || v_ssn);
 
 -- loop through cursor to get people
      v_found_ctr := 0;
    
      <<curs1_loop>>
      FOR curs1 IN c_person (v_first_name, v_last_name) LOOP
        BEGIN
          v_found_ctr := v_found_ctr + 1;


-- Write information to output file for review

            v_LinebuffOut := ('"' || v_found_ctr
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_id
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_fname
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_mi
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_lname
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_suffix
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_street1
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_street2
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_street3
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_city
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_state
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_zip
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_bdate
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || curs1.c_ssn
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || ' '
                    || '"' || v_crrt);
            UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_FileHandleOut,v_LinebuffOut);

        END;
      END LOOP curs1_loop;
      
      
      IF v_found_ctr = 0 THEN
         v_notes := 'No info found';
         v_LinebuffOut := ('"' || v_found_ctr
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || v_id
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || v_first_name
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || v_middle
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || v_last_name
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || v_suffix
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || ' '
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || ' '
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || ' '
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || ' '
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || ' '
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || ' '
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || v_birthdate
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || v_ssn
                    || '"' || v_field_sep || '"' || v_notes
                    || '"' || v_crrt);
         UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_FileHandleOut,v_LinebuffOut);
      
      END IF;

 <<NextRow>>
  END LOOP curs_loop;

-- Send email

  v_email_date := TO_CHAR(sysdate,'FMDY, dd MON YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ' -0600 (CST)'; 

  BEGIN
    message := 'Date: '    || v_email_date        || crlf ||
               'From: '    || v_recipient3        || crlf ||
               'Subject: ' || v_email_subject     || crlf ||
               'To: '      || v_recipient || crlf || crlf;

    message := message || 'CS office,'
                       || crlf
                       || crlf
                       || crlf
                       || crlf
                       || '   ' || crlf || crlf;

    mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(mailhost, 25);
    utl_smtp.helo(mail_conn, mailhost);
    utl_smtp.mail(mail_conn, sender);
    utl_smtp.rcpt(mail_conn, v_recipient);
    utl_smtp.rcpt(mail_conn, v_recipient2);
    utl_smtp.rcpt(mail_conn, v_recipient3);
    utl_smtp.data(mail_conn, message);
    utl_smtp.quit(mail_conn);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
  END;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing`END` right after `<<NextRow>>`. Should probably be like this:

```
DECLARE
   /* define the cursor for selecting a person based on first and last name. */
   CURSOR c_person (v_fname VARCHAR2, vlname VARCHAR2)
   IS
      SELECT DISTINCT i.spriden_id c_id,
                      i.spriden_first_name c_fname,
                      i.spriden_mi c_mi,
                      i.spriden_last_name c_lname,
                      p.spbpers_name_suffix c_suffix,
                      a.spraddr_street_line1 c_street1,
                      a.spraddr_street_line2 c_street2,
                      a.spraddr_street_line3 c_street3,
                      a.spraddr_city c_city,
                      a.spraddr_stat_code c_state,
                      a.spraddr_zip c_zip,
                      p.spbpers_birth_date c_bdate,
                      p.spbpers_ssn c_ssn
        FROM spriden i, spbpers p, spraddr a
       WHERE     i.spriden_pidm = p.spbpers_pidm
             AND i.spriden_pidm = a.spraddr_pidm
             AND a.spraddr_atyp_code = 'P'
             AND a.spraddr_to_date IS NULL
             AND UPPER (i.spriden_first_name) LIKE UPPER ('v_fname%')
             AND UPPER (i.spriden_last_name) LIKE UPPER ('v_lname');



   v_FileLocation      VARCHAR2 (290) := 'L';

   -- variables for input data file

   v_workfield         VARCHAR2 (255) := NULL;
   v_crn_count         NUMBER (4) := 0;

   -- END variables for input data file

   -- variables needed to verify input information and build output data file

   v_id                SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID%TYPE := NULL;
   v_pidm              SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM%TYPE := NULL;
   v_last_name         SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME%TYPE := NULL;
   v_first_name        SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME%TYPE := NULL;
   v_middle            SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_MI%TYPE := NULL;
   v_suffix            SPBPERS.SPBPERS_NAME_SUFFIX%TYPE := NULL;
   v_birthdate_in      SPBPERS.SPBPERS_BIRTH_DATE%TYPE := NULL;
   v_birthdate         SPBPERS.SPBPERS_BIRTH_DATE%TYPE := NULL;
   v_ssn_in            SPBPERS.SPBPERS_SSN%TYPE := NULL;
   v_ssn               SPBPERS.SPBPERS_SSN%TYPE := NULL;
   v_street1           SPRADDR.SPRADDR_STREET_LINE1%TYPE := NULL;
   v_street2           SPRADDR.SPRADDR_STREET_LINE2%TYPE := NULL;
   v_street3           SPRADDR.SPRADDR_STREET_LINE3%TYPE := NULL;
   v_city              SPRADDR.SPRADDR_CITY%TYPE := NULL;
   v_state             SPRADDR.SPRADDR_STAT_CODE%TYPE := NULL;
   v_zip               SPRADDR.SPRADDR_ZIP%TYPE := NULL;
   v_notes             VARCHAR2 (300) := ' ';
   v_lookup_ind        VARCHAR2 (1) := NULL;
   v_process_ind       VARCHAR2 (13) := NULL;


   -- END variables needed to verify input information and build output data file

   v_master_error      VARCHAR2 (1) := 'N';
   v_process_flag      VARCHAR2 (3) := 'Y';
   v_process_ctr       NUMBER := '0';
   v_insert_ctr        NUMBER := '0';
   v_found_ctr         NUMBER := '0';
   v_master_error_ctr  NUMBER := '0';
   v_fatal_comment     VARCHAR2 (13) := NULL;
   v_error_code        VARCHAR2 (13) := NULL;
   v_error_messages    VARCHAR2 (13) := NULL;
   v_row_error         VARCHAR2 (13) := NULL;

   -- variables for output and input data files

   v_field_sep         VARCHAR2 (4) := CHR (009);

   v_InPathname        VARCHAR2 (55) := 'SNC_READ_AREA';
   v_InFilename        VARCHAR2 (355) := '&DataInFile';
   v_LinebuffIn        VARCHAR2 (300) := NULL;
   v_FileHandleIn      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

   v_crrt              VARCHAR2 (4) := CHR (013);

   v_OutPathname       VARCHAR2 (55) := 'SNC_WRITE_AREA';
   v_OutFilename       VARCHAR2 (355) := '&DataOutFile';
   v_LinebuffOut       VARCHAR2 (6000);
   v_FileHandleOut     UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

   -- END variables for output and input data files

   -- variables for Emailing

   MESSAGE             VARCHAR2 (31000) := NULL;
   v_tab               VARCHAR2 (6) := CHR (009);
   crlf                VARCHAR2 (2) := CHR (13) || CHR (10);
   mailhost            VARCHAR2 (30) := 'cwisrelay.snc.edu';
   mail_conn           UTL_SMTP.connection;
   sender              VARCHAR2 (90) := 'darlene.blaney@snc.edu';
   v_recipient         VARCHAR2 (90) := '&EmailTo1';
   v_email_subject     VARCHAR2 (160)
                          := 'CS - Data Processing for ' || v_InFilename;
   v_email_date        VARCHAR2 (250) := NULL;
-- END variables for Emailing


-- Core program

BEGIN
   v_FileHandleOut := UTL_FILE.FOPEN (v_OutPathname, v_OutFilename, 'W');

   v_LinebuffOut :=
      (   '"SequenceNo"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"Banner ID"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"First Name"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"Middle"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"Last Name"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"Suffix"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"Street1"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"Street2"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"Street3"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"City"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"State"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"Zip"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"BirthDate"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"SSN"'
       || v_field_sep
       || '"Notes"'
       || v_crrt);
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (v_FileHandleOut, v_LinebuffOut);

   v_FileHandleIn := UTL_FILE.fopen (v_InPathname, v_InFilename, 'R');

  <<curs_loop>>
   WHILE v_process_flag = 'Y'
   LOOP
      --    v_fatal_comment := NULL;
      --    v_master_error := 'N';
      v_process_flag := 'Y';

      -- Get the next row and get the necessary values

      BEGIN
         UTL_FILE.get_line (v_FileHandleIn, v_LinebuffIn);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('INVALID_PATH');
            UTL_FILE.fclose_all;
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            v_process_flag := 'N';
            GOTO NextRow;
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            v_error_code := SQLCODE;
            v_error_messages := v_error_messages || SQLERRM || crlf;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
                  'Error: '
               || v_error_code
               || ' '
               || SQLERRM
               || '  '
               || v_process_ctr);
            v_process_flag := 'N';
            GOTO NextRow;
      END;

      -- Input File - Position 1 - First Name

      v_workfield :=
         SUBSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                 1,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          1)
                 - 1);
      v_workfield := UPPER (v_workfield);
      v_workfield := TRIM (v_workfield);
      v_workfield := NVL (v_workfield, 'END');
      v_first_name := v_workfield;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 1: ' || v_workfield);

      IF v_workfield = 'END'
      THEN
         v_process_flag := 'N';
         v_row_error := 'N';
         GOTO NextRow;
      ELSIF v_workfield = 'FIRST'
      THEN
         GOTO NextRow;
      END IF;


      -- Input File - Position 2 - Middle Name

      v_workfield :=
         SUBSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          1)
                 + 1,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          2)
                 - INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          1)
                 - 1);
      v_workfield := UPPER (v_workfield);
      v_workfield := TRIM (v_workfield);
      v_middle := NVL (v_workfield, '');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 2: ' || v_middle);

      -- Input File = Position 3 - Last Name

      v_workfield :=
         SUBSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          2)
                 + 1,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          3)
                 - INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          2)
                 - 1);
      v_workfield := TRIM (v_workfield);
      v_workfield := NVL (v_workfield, '');
      v_last_name := v_workfield;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 3: ' || v_last_name);

      -- Input File - Position 4 - Suffix

      v_workfield :=
         SUBSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          3)
                 + 1,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          4)
                 - INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          3)
                 - 1);
      v_workfield := TRIM (v_workfield);
      v_workfield := UPPER (v_workfield);
      v_suffix := NVL (v_suffix, '');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 4: ' || v_suffix);

      -- Input File - Position 5 - Date of Birth

      v_workfield :=
         SUBSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          4)
                 + 1,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          5)
                 - INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          4)
                 - 1);
      v_workfield := TRIM (v_workfield);
      v_workfield := UPPER (v_workfield);
      v_workfield := REPLACE (v_workfield, ' ', '');
      v_workfield := REPLACE (v_workfield, ',', '');
      v_workfield := NVL (v_workfield, 'NODATE');

      IF (    SUBSTR (v_workfield, 2, 1) <> '/'
          AND SUBSTR (v_workfield, 3, 1) <> '/')
      THEN
         v_workfield := 'NODATE';
      END IF;

      IF v_workfield = 'NODATE'
      THEN
         v_birthdate_in := NULL;
      ELSE
         BEGIN
            v_birthdate_in := TO_DATE (v_workfield, 'mm/dd/YYYY');
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN VALUE_ERROR
            THEN
               v_birthdate_in := NULL;
               v_row_error := 'Y';
               v_error_messages :=
                     v_error_messages
                  || '  Fatal: R'
                  || v_process_ctr
                  || ' Invalid Date (birthdate).'
                  || v_crlf;
         END;
      END IF;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 5: ' || v_birthdate);

      -- Input File - Position 6 - SSN

      v_workfield :=
         SUBSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          5)
                 + 1,
                   INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          6)
                 - INSTR (v_LinebuffIn,
                          v_field_sep,
                          1,
                          5)
                 - 1);
      v_workfield := TRIM (v_workfield);
      v_workfield := UPPER (v_workfield);
      v_workfield := NVL (v_workfield, '00');
      v_ssn := LPAD (v_ssn, 9, '0');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Position 6: ' || v_ssn);

      -- loop through cursor to get people
      v_found_ctr := 0;

     <<curs1_loop>>
      FOR curs1 IN c_person (v_first_name, v_last_name)
      LOOP
         BEGIN
            v_found_ctr := v_found_ctr + 1;


            -- Write information to output file for review

            v_LinebuffOut :=
               (   '"'
                || v_found_ctr
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_id
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_fname
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_mi
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_lname
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_suffix
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_street1
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_street2
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_street3
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_city
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_state
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_zip
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_bdate
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || curs1.c_ssn
                || '"'
                || v_field_sep
                || '"'
                || ' '
                || '"'
                || v_crrt);
            UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (v_FileHandleOut, v_LinebuffOut);
         END;
      END LOOP curs1_loop;


      IF v_found_ctr = 0
      THEN
         v_notes := 'No info found';
         v_LinebuffOut :=
            (   '"'
             || v_found_ctr
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || v_id
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || v_first_name
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || v_middle
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || v_last_name
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || v_suffix
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || ' '
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || ' '
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || ' '
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || ' '
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || ' '
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || ' '
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || v_birthdate
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || v_ssn
             || '"'
             || v_field_sep
             || '"'
             || v_notes
             || '"'
             || v_crrt);
         UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (v_FileHandleOut, v_LinebuffOut);
      END IF;

     <<NextRow>>
      end;
   END LOOP curs_loop;

   -- Send email

   v_email_date :=
      TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'FMDY, dd MON YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ' -0600 (CST)';

   BEGIN
      MESSAGE :=
            'Date: '
         || v_email_date
         || crlf
         || 'From: '
         || v_recipient3
         || crlf
         || 'Subject: '
         || v_email_subject
         || crlf
         || 'To: '
         || v_recipient
         || crlf
         || crlf;

      MESSAGE :=
            MESSAGE
         || 'CS office,'
         || crlf
         || crlf
         || crlf
         || crlf
         || '   '
         || crlf
         || crlf;

      mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection (mailhost, 25);
      UTL_SMTP.helo (mail_conn, mailhost);
      UTL_SMTP.mail (mail_conn, sender);
      UTL_SMTP.rcpt (mail_conn, v_recipient);
      UTL_SMTP.rcpt (mail_conn, v_recipient2);
      UTL_SMTP.rcpt (mail_conn, v_recipient3);
      UTL_SMTP.data (mail_conn, MESSAGE);
      UTL_SMTP.quit (mail_conn);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         NULL;
   END;
END;
/
```